# Noncommutative probability puzzles?

Tags: probability, big-list, noncommutative-algebra

Probability is fun mainly because of the many puzzles. Are there any puzzles in noncommutative probability?

I would guess that quantum mechanics could offer puzzles like those, but I can't find any.

Comment: In QM non-commutative are observables (which can be viewed as random variables), not probabilities. If you try to build joint distribution of non-commuting random variables you end up with violating probability axioms (for example, you get negative probabilities). An example of such "puzzle" is [Wigner distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution)

Comment: @kludg Can Wigner distribution be turned into a gamble game?

Comment: I am not aware about the games with Wigner distribution, physicists use other games to explain peculiarities of QM, most known is [CHSH game](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2016/10/26/chsh-game-in-detail/)

Answer (score 1):

There is the quantum version of the Monty Hall problem; see [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0202120) arxiv paper.